# Rails how to copy the index id of a specific controller so I can then access that controller data table into a new controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a question.. so i have a data in let say invoice table which contains invoice number, amount etc.. and i want to create an edit button but that edit button would not be the edit in the invoice controller but instead in the separate new controller, which would be calling new how would i display the details of that invoice tab to that new controller

like how to link the id of that specific invoice index to the new data set so that i can put that data into a new seperate table

[see image of what i mean.. so when i press the delivery fulfillment button, it goes to the codes controller index but i want to read the id of the invoice so it can display the info there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNy62.png)

Comment: There's a lot to unwrap here. I can point out a few high level thoughts I have with the limited information available. 1. Controllers don't really have IDs, models do. 2. I'd think you would want all your invoice actions in the same controller but in different methods. It would be helpful to see you invoice model and the controller methods in question.

Comment: pass it as params to that new action.